# Assuming we have implemented a PriorityQueue as a heap, what is the runtime of converting the heap to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime, heap

I understand that Java implements PriorityQueue internally as a heap. I'm not sure what the runtime of PriorityQueue.toArray() is. I imagine you'd have to remove each element from the min (or max) heap one by one and then insert each into an array, giving O(nlogn) complexity.

Comment: `toArray` does not return a sorted array

Comment: A priority heap *is* an array. Runtime is *O(N)* as all it does is copy. No sorting. See the Javadoc.